# Where the promotion rules get applied in code in magento

Tags: magento

When we create some promotion or shopping cart rule, i want where exactly the parsing and application of rule takes place in code.

I know it goes here : Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule but not able to figure it out completely.

-Thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can start from `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator` class
method `process`. 
It processes every shopping cart item, and check if any cart rule can apply to it. It easy to see which rules were applied.
Rule have `validate` method.

```
/**
 * Validate rule conditions to determine if rule can run
 *
 * @param Varien_Object $object
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function validate(Varien_Object $object)
{
    return $this->getConditions()->validate($object);
}
```

This call starts recursive Condition parsing in `Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Combine` class.

That operates with `Condition` class hierarchy (see Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_*).
Also you can quickly view conditions structure by calling `$rule->getConditions()->asArray()`.